# Change Notepad++ Double Click Highlight Behavior

Tags: notepad++

It seems like the double click function in NotePad++ currently highlights all text until it finds a space or non-alphanumeric character. If I double click on the 'F00D' portion of the following guid:

```
0BADC0DE-DEAD-B33F-F00D-C0FFEE00C0D3
```

It will select 'F00D'. Is there a way to have the double click functionality extend to the entire Guid? In essence, I want the double click to highlight in either direction until it finds a space. So in the previous example, a double click anywhere in the Guid would select the entire Guid.

I tried changing the Settings -> Preferences -> Delimiter setting to a blank space on either side, but no luck still.

Comment: If the GUID is on it's own on a line then triple click will highlight the whole thing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Settings > Preferences > Delimiter > Add your character as part of word.

Please a hyphen '-' in this field and it will add the hyphen character as part of the word character set, and therefore highlight the entire GUID string as it accepts the hyphen as being treated as any other standard alphanumeric character.

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Begin/End Select` function

Right-Click before the first character of the GUID, select `Begin/End Select`

Right-Click after the last character of the GUID, select `Begin/End Select`

This will select the entire GUID

It's a few extra clicks but gets the desired result

Comment: This is even worse than left-click, hold and drag

Comment: I didn't say it was better or worse than any other method.

Comment: I learned something from this and, though it is tedious, I don't believe it's enough for a downvote. I upvoted to counter.

Answer (score 0):

When using the `Settings` -> `Preferences` -> `Delimiter` setting you need to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Double Click

Set both `Open` and `Close` to a single space

Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Double Click on the GUID.

I have just tested this and it works, but only if there is a space + [text] before and after the GUID. This might be a bug in notepad++.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for me. It still only selects the 'F00D' portion of the guid.

Comment: Works fine for me on 2 different computers. What version are you using? I have 6.5.2

Comment: Hmm, I also have 6.5.2.Just to make absolutely sure we're doing the same thing: I hold down ctl and then double left click the left mouse button?

Comment: I've done some further testing. This ONLY works if there's a space BOTH ends of the GUID:

`word GUID` - doesn't work (sometimes crashes Notepad++!)
`GUID word` - doesn't work (sometimes crashes Notepad++!)
`word GUID word` does work

Comment: Yep, that's the same behavior that I have. This seems like a notepad++ bug.

Comment: note that you can have asymmetric open and close. In other words, you can change it to have an open of ` ` (space) and a close of `_`.  However, this does not do "greedy" selection. If your "phrase" includes multiple underscores (e.g. this_is_my_phrase), you can only control+doubleclick in the first "word" (`this`) to get anything other than the whole phrase.